# How to combine multiple variable data to a single variable data?

Tags: r, phyloseq

After making my data frame, and selecting the variables i want to look at, i face a dilemma. The excel sheet which acts as my data source was used by different people recording the same type of data.

```
Mock     Neg Neg1PCR Neg2PCR  NegPBS     red     Red RedWine   water   Water   white   White 
  1       9       1       1       1       2      18       4       4       4       2      26
```

As you can see, because the data is written diffently, Major groups (Redwine, Whitewine and Water) have now been split into undergroups . How do i combine the undergroups into a combined group eg. red+Red+RedWine -> Total wine. I use the phyloseq package for this kind of dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names <- c("red","white","water")
df2 <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(names), nrow = nrow(df))),names)

for(col in names){
  df2[,col] <- rowSums(df[,grep(col,tolower(names(df)))])
}
```

here

```
grep(col,tolower(names(df)))
```

looks for all the column names that contain the strings like "red" in the names of your vector. You then just sum them in a new data.frame `df2` defined with the good lengths

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a new data.frame, easiest to do with dplyr but also doable with base R:

with dplyr

`newFrame <- oldFrame %>% mutate(Mock = Mock, Neg = Neg + Neg1PCR + Neg2PCR + NegPBS, Red = red + Red + RedWine, Water = water + Water, White = white = White)`

with base R (not complete but you get the point)

`newFrame <- data.frame(Red = oldFrame$Red + oldFrame$red + oldFrame$RedWine...)`

Answer (score 0):

One can use `dplyr:starts_with` and `dplyr::select` to combine columns. The `ignore.case` is by default `TRUE` in `dplyr:starts_with` with help in the data.frame OP has posted.

```
library(dplyr)
names <- c("red", "white", "water")
cbind(df[1], t(mapply(function(x)rowSums(select(df, starts_with(x))), names)))

#   Mock red white water
# 1    1  24    28     8
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Mock   Neg Neg1PCR Neg2PCR  NegPBS     red   Red  RedWine   water   Water   white   White 
1       9       1       1       1       2      18       4       4       4       2      26",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```